# Why is this answer with an undisclosed affiliated blog link not Spam?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012494/6471538) answer as Spam.

The user answering the question is named Ammar Al Hashmi, and in his answer, he links to a blog with the same name at the top, and the link to the blog also includes the folder name "@ahashmi06", which was what clued me in to the undisclosed relationship.

My Spam flag was Declined.

> spam – Robert Columbia 14 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why is this answer not Spam?

I realize that I could have edited out the link, but [we are not supposed to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited).

I did downvote the answer.

Comment: You got that one wrong.  No real harm done, we can vote it back up.

Comment: It's worth noting that the answer here is largely copy-pasted from the linked blog post, there is very little original content in the answer. The majority of it could be encased in block-quotes, and editing out the attribution is really not appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

It was probably declined because spam posts are *just* spam. This answer was not; it contained real, useful information which (presumably) answered the question. It also happened to include a link to the answer's blog, but that link was in no way *essential* to the answer.

That's not a spam post. Spam flags are for when someone posts a content-less answer containing a link to their website.

You could have just edited "please refer to the post" into "please refer to my post".

Comment: The reference could also be edited out and the answer would still stand on its own which I would say is another reason to keep the post around and not hit it with a spam flag.

Comment: Note that certain spamers use valid text to post their spam. This is known since '13 https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7218/169736